# Is there an equivalent setting in Apache (on a UNIX box) to prompt user login to view a site as Windows Authentication does in IIS?

Tags: apache, unix, authentication, web

I have been requested to setup a test site written in php, on a unix box. I have been given the site files and it is loading fine but I need to close it off from anonymous access. Is there a setting in Apache server that allows this to be done in the same way that Windows Authentication would in IIS. I understand that a login page could be added to the site but I am not a php developer and wanted to take advantage of existing functionality if it's there.

Thanks.

Comment: You could use `.htaccess` in conjunction with an `.htpasswd` file. Checkout this link: http://weavervsworld.com/docs/other/passprotect.html

Comment: Your link looks very useful, thanks. Could you post it as an answer and I'll upvote.

Comment: I added a short answer=)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to add an `.htaccess` file with something like this in your webroot:

```
AuthUserFile /<path>/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Your Auth Name"
Require valid-user
```

Then you would need to add a `.htpasswd` file with your login credentials.

To add a `.htpasswd` file you could open your terminal and execute the following command:

```
htpasswd -c -b .htpasswd username password
```

The above will create a file name `.htpasswd` with `username/password` as login in the current directory.

Reference: [Password Protection with .htaccess & .htpasswd](http://weavervsworld.com/docs/other/passprotect.html)